# How to tell Google to recognize mobile-version and full-version of the web?

Tags: seo, mobile-website

I have created mobile-optimized version of my web. Full version runs at www.domain.com and the mobile version runs at m.domain.com. Now I DO want to use this domain scheme for certain reasons.

Now when I try to search Google, sometimes I get results from both domains - which I don't think is good experience for the users - coming with desktop browser to a simple mobile-version of the web. Also I want to avoid duplicate-content problem.

What would be the best practice to "tell" Google that www.domain.com is full version website and m.domain.com is the website with the same content but with very simple design optimised for mobile users ?

Comment: Is there a one-to-one correspondence between the URLs?

Comment: Yes, the URLs are exactly the same, so www.domain.com/url1 has the same content as m.domain.com/url1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `m.` URLs redirect (or `<link rel="canonical">`) to desktop URLs for spider UAs.

Make desktop URLs redirect to `m.` URLs for mobile UAs.

Comment: I don't want to redirect real human visitors. Is it then OK if I redirect just spiders the way you have suggested ? It's not cloaking issue or anything forbidden by search engines ?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with redirecting crawlers to non-mobile URLs.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just for answer to be complete - which type of HTTP redirect I should do for this kind of situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use

```
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://mobileversion..."/>
```

Comment: By googling I have found, that <link rel="alternate" media="handheld" ... is for specifying WAP mobile pages... My mobile webpage is regular HTML page, but with very simple graphics and CSS. So I think this wouldn't apply to my situation.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. "handheld: Intended for handheld devices (typically small screen, limited bandwidth) (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) .Although tag actually stops google from transcoding your pages together with a mobile doctype on mobile site you can give hint about your mobile site. You can also see http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35312 there is no mentioning of wml/wap

Answer (score 0):

You should add a rel alternate on your desktop that points to the mobile URL and a rel conical on the mobile site that points to the desktop. For more clarity on this watch the video by Google's Matt Cutts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVQHbfpqXHM